# Boolean index Numpy array with sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to apply a Boolean index on a numpy array via a sparse matrix.

```
A = dense n x n matrix, where n is large

B = sparse n x n Boolean matrix
```

Example operations:

```
A[B] *= 2

A[~B] *= -2
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this without converting the sparse matrix into a dense matrix (which causes memory issues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the row and column indices associated with non-zero (i.e. True) values in your sparse matrix by converting it to COO format:

```
B = B.tocoo()
```

then

```
A[B.row, B.col] *= 2
```

avoids converting `B` to a dense matrix.

---

If `B` is sparse then `~B` is quite dense.
To handle `A[~B] *= -2` efficiently, we should try to avoid evaluating `~B` directly. 
Instead, we could multiply by `-2` everywhere:

```
A *= -2
```

and then repair those locations where `B` is True:

```
A[B.row, B.col] *= -1/2
```